# Find value for $x$ for which $e^y \frac {dy}{dx} = 6$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, exponential-function

Find value for $x$ for which 
$$e^y \frac {dy}{dx} = 6$$

All help appreciated. All working please.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: The answer would contain a constant. Are you sure no set of values for (x,y) are given?

Comment: integrate both sides.  $e^y = 6x+ C, y = \ln(6x+C)$

Comment: Either give $y$ as a function of $x$ or require that the equality is valid for all $x$.

Answer (score 2):

This is a rather simple differential equation to solve, as its already in separable form :

$$e^y \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=6 \Rightarrow \int e^y\mathrm{d}y = \int6\mathrm{d}x \Leftrightarrow e^y= 6x + c \Leftrightarrow y(x) = \ln(6x+c)$$

Now, if you yield an initial condition $y(0) = y_0$, one would get for the constant $c$ :

$$y(0) = y_0 \Rightarrow \ln(c) = y_0 \Leftrightarrow c = e^{y_0}$$